# How to Fix Faulty Redirect From ASP.NET Login Controls?

Tags: asp.net, controls, membership

I have a website hosted on GoDaddy. Url is www.boatronix.com. The files Reside in a folder  '/boatronix' which in turn is in a folder '/_sites.' I have a master page which contains a SiteNav.ascx (that sits in a "Controls" folder under the root directory) and it has page links all with urls of "../sales.aspx" or "../operations.aspx" and so on. When I go to one of the pages, all in the same root directory, I get a page with an address bar above "boatronix.com/sales.aspx" just like it should.

I also have ASP.net membership Login Controls on the master page, and one of the nav links points to a restricted page. When I am redirected to login.aspx from either route (requesting the restricted page OR clicking the 'login' button in the loginStatus control) I am taken to the login.aspx, but with an address bar above that is now appended "boatronix.com/_sites/boatronix/login.aspx."

Problem:  this is an undesireable result, because the returnUrl in the query string, and then every subsequent page request is then searched as "boatronix.com/_sites/boatronix/page.aspx" and so my nav links are all now broken.

My question:  Is the scripting for the login controls' 'doPostBack' functionality to blame--this is what GoDaddy's tech line tells me is the problem; OR, do I need to fix this in IIS, or in my code, or my web.config? (for instance, setting any virtual directory rules)

If you go to the site "www.boatronix.com" and click the "Login" link on the upper right, you'll see what happens as the page request seems to trace back one directory from '/boatronix' to '_sites' and then proceed from there--I'm trying to stop it from doing that and keep in the root directory.

Thx much for looking and any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Very hard to figure out what your issue is without seeing your site's structure completely, but it sounds like you'll need to adjust your login page URL in your Web.Config.

When you access any protected page ASP.NET will direct you to the login url with the referring page in the query string parameter with the key `ReturnURL`. If you want to adjust where that redirect goes to then you need to adjust the `loginUrl` location in the Web.Config.

Such as

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

See: [Authentication Web.Config on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22HTTP://SCHEMAS.MICROSOFT.COM/.NETCONFIGURATION/V2.0#@LOGINURL%22%29;k%28%22HTTP://SCHEMAS.MICROSOFT.COM/.NETCONFIGURATION/V2.0#CONFIGURATION/SYSTEM.WEB/AUTHENTICATION/FORMS%22%29;k%28%22HTTP://SCHEMAS.MICROSOFT.COM/.NETCONFIGURATION/V2.0#FORMS%22%29;k%28VS.XMLEDITOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried "/login.aspx" "login.aspx" "../login.aspx" and "~/login.aspx" and none of these has fixed it. The redirect always seems to look back one directory, and the returnUrl is similarly appended.